# Adding elements to an array using useRecoilState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, recoiljs

I am trying to make a ToDo list using recoil. I used useSetRecoilState to add a new todo to the list and tried to print it in the main. But for some reason, the elements of todos I add to the list becomes undefined. The values that I inserted in the setToDoList were fine.
Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Here are the codes.

```
////recoil_state.js////
import { atom, selector } from "recoil";

export const toDoListState = atom({
    key: "toDoListState",
    default: [],
})

export const filterState = atom({
    key: "filterState",
    default: ["",""],
})

export const filteredToDoListState = selector({
    key: "filteredToDoListState",
    get: ({get}) => {
        const filter = get(filterState);
        const list = get(toDoListState);

        if (filter[0]=="" && filter[1]==""){
            return list;
        } else if (filter[0]==""){
            return list.filter((item) => item.date<=filter[1]);
        } else if (filter[1]==""){
            return list.filter((item) => item.date>=filter[0]);
        } else {
            return list.filter((item) => item.date>=filter[0] || item.date<=filter[1]);
        }
    }
})
```

```
////ToDoCreator.js////
import { useRef } from "react";
import { useSetRecoilState } from "recoil";
import { toDoListState } from "../recoil_state.js"

export default function ToDoCreator(){
    const idRef = useRef(null);
    const todoRef = useRef(null);
    const dateRef = useRef(null);
    const setToDoList = useSetRecoilState(toDoListState);

    const create =() => {
        if(idRef.current.value=="" || todoRef.current.value=="" || dateRef.current.value==""){
            alert("All fields required!");
        } else if(isNaN(idRef.current.value)){
            alert("ID must be a number!");
        } else if(!Date.parse(dateRef.current.value)){
            alert("Invalide Date!");
        } else{
            setToDoList((current) => [
                ...current,
                {
                    id: Number(idRef.current.value),
                    text: todoRef.current.value,
                    date: new Date(dateRef.current.value),
                }
            ]);
            //alert(`${idRef.current.value} ${todoRef.current.value} ${new Date(dateRef.current.value)}`)
            idRef.current.value="";
            todoRef.current.value="";
            dateRef.current.value="";
        }
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="ID" ref={idRef} />
            <input type="text" placeholder="To-Do" ref={todoRef} />
            <input type="text" placeholder="Date" ref={dateRef} />
            <button onClick={create}>Save</button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the way you are trying to render the object is the problem here. I ran your code and it works fine for me.

Change:
`const setToDoList = useSetRecoilState(toDoListState);`

to:
`const [toDoList, setToDoList] = useRecoilState(toDoListState);`

Also, modify your return to:

```
return (
<div>
  <input type="text" placeholder="ID" ref={idRef} />
  <input type="text" placeholder="To-Do" ref={todoRef} />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Date" ref={dateRef} />
  <button onClick={create}>Save</button>

    {toDoList.map((item) => (
      <div key={item.id}>
        {item.id}: {item.text}
      </div>
    ))}
</div>
);
```

Then you should see output like this:
[image]

I doubt this link will withstand the test of time, but here is the sandbox I used:

https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-engelbart-yeesx2?file=/src/todo_creator.tsx